# How can I increase the speed of many insert statements?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sqlcommand

I have a .NET project that is receiving data, processing it, and then writing it to a SQLServer database. Let's say I have the following code.

```
Private Sub InsertRecord(val1 As Integer, val2 As Integer, ByRef dbConnection As      Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
    If dbConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Dim strSql As String = "Insert Into MyTable(Value1, Value2) Values(@Value1, @Value2)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(strSql, dbConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", val1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", val2)
        Dim returnVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If Not returnVal Then
            'do other stuff
        End If
        cmd.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

Sometimes I need to insert records quickly - say 500 per second. As is, it can only handle around 200 inserts per second. Is there some way to combine multiple commands to be processed at once? I need to know the results of each insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need SQL Server bulk insert as made available through the `SqlBulkCopy` class. Use one transaction for all rows. It will be blindingly fast.

Indexing also plays into this, as well as many other things. Not enough information here to comment specifically.